# Purchasing laptop for more than 10 hours usage?

Tags: laptop

I would like to replace my aging desktop with a laptop. However, during the weekend I might work on the laptop for more than 12 hours.

Will laptop overheat after long usage? are they suitable for long usage?

Comment: If the laptop has temperature problems, this will show up within minutes under load, not after hours.

Comment: Depends on what you're running, where you are, what you buy, your set up environment, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you aren't going to be maxing the CPU at 100% for 24 hours a day, any modern laptop won't overheat. Even if you do use it 24 hours a day at 100% usage, it should still be fine. I've run my laptops pretty hard over the years without any heat issues (being dropped, kicked, stepped on by kids, etc is a different story..)

Comment: I live in a tropical country. Hot and humid, pretty dusty as well. How do I prevent dust from getting into my laptop fan. I uses vacuum cleaner on my desktop fans and casing ventilation holes.